# Why my sticker doesn't work after (maybe)2 weeks?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-stickers

I made my own iMessage stickers, which I installed to my and my brother's iPhone, without a dev account.

After maybe 2 weeks, stickers stopped work on my iPhone as well as iPhone of my brother. I have to delete it, and install it again.

Is there any time limit of the provisioning profile, how long it works without dev account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free provisioning expires in 7 days (previously it was 90 days), you can see the expiration date in Xcode selecting the `i` icon near the provisioning profile like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Great, I would like to also ask, if I have dev account, I am able to use it without any limitation?

Comment: Of time? iOS provisioning profiles for in-house apps (with a dev account) are valid for 12 months.